# Trim function does not work properly or is inconsistent postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

I am trying to trim a string in the table using the trim function, i noticed that some work and some half work and some dont work at all..

this is my code:

```
select trim(image_url, '//testamplify.amazonaws.co/public/restaurant/'), image_url
from scimage s 
where ref_id isnull and ref_type = '1'
```

I am trying to trim this //testamplify.amazonaws.co/public/restaurant/Carnitas-Tacos.png
just the first part and leave the rest to get 'Carnitas-Tacos.png

the results i am getting is the letter 'g' It doesnt seem to be triming properly
anyone know why that is.

Comment: `trim` does not work like that. Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). You need `replace(image_url, '//testamplify.amazonaws.co/public/restaurant/', '')` instead.

Comment: Works for me: `select trim('//testamplify.amazonaws.co/public/restaurant/Carnitas-Tacos.png' , '//testamplify.amazonaws.co/public/restaurant/'); Carnitas-Tacos.png`.